# Apply scale factor to gltf import in python api

Tags: transforms, import, gltf, units

So, I am using the python interface to import a very complex model from a different application that uses cm and not meters, and I would like to downscale everything by 0.01 (still using python) to make units correct in blender. I see the import commands sometimes have scale factors, but the gltf one incidentally doesn't, as far as I can tell.

Since the model is extremely complex, filled with empty objects that serve only to provide position relationships between many thousands of objects, I am not sure of the safest way of applying a scale factor to the entire newly imported set of objects. I am wondering if I am missing some obvious option?... If I do scale, note that I need both the size and the position to be all scaled by 0.01: it would of course be super ugly if the sizes changed by 100x but the relative origin for the scaling wasn't the origin of the global coordinate system :-D

Thanks a lot for any ideas or thoughts!! (And again, sorry if this is a stupid question. I am new to the blender python API, but I am loving it so far :-D )

Answer (score 1):

It's kind of a hack, but you can do this by setting the scene's **Unit Scale** to 100 before you import the glTF file. Then reset it afterwards.

The Unit Scale is in the Properties Editor under the Scene tab.

[image: Unit Scale in the Properties Editor]

This works because the unit scale is in meters/(blender unit). A glTF file stores lengths in meters, so the importer divides by the unit scale to convert lengths to blender units.

Note that

- due to [a bug](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-IO/issues/1439), camera near/far distances are not scaled
- unlike the importer, the glTF exporter does NOT take the unit scale into account